# Nonexistent "accept" button in iTunes Terms & Conditions Page

Tags: itunes, movie

I recently bought "The Bourne: Ultimate Collection" for Blu-ray and Digital HD and along with my purchase, I received a Digital HD slip that has movie codes for all the included movies in the collection. Great deal actually!

Anyway, I've logged into iTunes, clicked redeem and entered the code for the first movie. But, before it continues to the download a sentence pops up underneath the redemption bar that states in red:

> You must read and agree to the new Terms and Conditions in order to proceed.

Well, that's all fine and dandy. However, when I open the Terms and Conditions page on iTunes **there exists no "Accept" button at the bottom of the page.**

I've searched several forums pages on iTunes support but have only been able to find the following: their solution was to change the payment method to *none* because iTunes no longer accepts PayPal… my payment method is already set to none.

Comment: In some cases I have seen the accept button not appear unless you scroll down to the bottom of the Terms and Conditions. Click on that text and try to scroll down (mouse wheel, trackpad scroll, arrows or Page Down keys) and see if that does anything...

Comment: @SteveChambers I have scrolled to the bottom of the Terms and Conditions several times after clicking the link. I still have no luck. Here's what it states at the top of the page: These terms and conditions create a contract between you and Apple (the “Agreement”). Please read the Agreement carefully. To confirm your understanding and acceptance of the Agreement, click “Agree.” But nowhere at the bottom or top for that matter, is there a place where I can "click 'Agree.'" Why is this so complicated??